# Render multiple jades in a single function nodejs

Tags: node.js, rendering, pug

I was looking to do several shows render in nodejs mistake I happened as follows:

```
res.render ('header', {
   title: 'demo'
});

res.render ('main', {
   container: 'dataaa'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use [include](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/) instead

```
//- layout.jade
doctype html
html
  include ./head.jade
  body
    include ./main.jade
```

then

```
res.render ('layout', {
    title: 'demo',
    container: 'dataaa'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
the original idea is to obtain two collections to two files in jade

unoCollection var = db.get ( 'one');

unoCollection.findById (id, function (err, result) {
    res.render ('header', {
       name: result.name,
       surname: result.surname,
    });
});


unoCollection var = db.get ('two');

unoCollection.find ({}, function (err, result) {
    res.render ('users', {
     name: result.name,
      surname: result.surname,
   });
});

and jade
html
   body
     include header.jade
      include usuarios.jade

It does not work this way there somehow?
```